# Looking for a simple 3d visualization solution that works in browser

Tags: 3d, visualization

I am looking for a 3D visualization solution that will work in browsers with no additional plugins installed. The need is to have a 3D models of few  houses and the user should be able to change the colors the of walls. Main thing is that it should be really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

What most of the 3D visualization and CAD software companies out there are doing today is using whatever they like and host it inside [Frame](http://www.fra.me) platform. You completely bypass the browser issue and make your app usable from any device: I mean any!